# Passing YAML payload through API Gateway to Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I was wondering if one can actually pass YAML payload format using API Gateway POST method to AWS Lambda function. I don't want any models for the payload or any checking of the payload using templates. I just want to pass the data to Lambda in YAML format. Has anyone ever successfully achieved this?

I was earlier using JSON payload to pass the payload to Lambda, but due to certain design issues I felt YAML format payload is better suited for the task. I tried passing the YAML payload in the request body but was getting the following error. I kept method request header as **Accept:application/yaml**. I kept request body Content Type in Method Request as **application/yaml**.

```
Thu Aug 15 23:47:58 UTC 2019 : Lambda invocation failed with status: 400. Lambda request id: 66991273-f3fd-427f-85a3-eafe4f94251b
Thu Aug 15 23:47:58 UTC 2019 : Execution failed: Could not parse request body into json:
```

I also searched the documentation and couldn't find much about the same. I wonder if this is supported at all. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

API Gateway supports parsing and validation of only [JSON payloads](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/models-mappings.html). One workaround solution will be lambda function handling the payload. Set content type to plain text, inside the lambda function, parse the request body and validate.

[Request body can be retrieved from `event.body` when the Lambda Proxy Integration is enabled.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format)

Comment: Yes. I was thinking of validating the payload in Lambda after passing the YAML payload anyhow. I did as you said similar to what suggested here. https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/6219kx/api_gateway_non_json_inputs_textplain/

But  my Lambda isn't catching the payload. It's blank. Don't know why. ```{"Body": ""}```

Comment: I think you're not using lambda proxy integration. [Request body can be retrieved as a string from the `event` variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format). I'll add it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your Mapping Templates of the Request Integration part, please add a mapping like this: application/yaml, and the templete should be generated with "method request passthrough" option.

Then in your lambda, you will receive the raw yaml payload -> you must parse/validate model by yourself.

Please see attached screenshot.

[image: Mapping Template]